# What is the difference between using enter and using \r\n in a string

Tags: php, enter

what is the difference between using enter and \r\n in a string?

e.g.

```
$mystring="
";
```

vs

```
$mystring="\r\n";
```

Comment: Better to use the constant `PHP_EOL`, this will translate to the correct line ending depending on the server's OS

Answer (score 0):

Entering wouldn't actually do anything. \r\n are mostly used on Windows, \n is used on Unix systems, all for line breaking.

Comment: I could actually create a text file with either of those though.

Comment: @ralphcuneta_user3530269 Yup, both should do the trick. But you should use either one of those as opposed to using enter. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Enter in a string makes Error sometimes in Most of the Languages. If you are mean to add Enter in Your string you have to use special character like \r\n. These Special characters are interpreted as New line but Using the Enter are compiled as new line of code, not the new line of String.